# How to convert List<T> to Flux<T> by using Reactor 3.x

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Asyn call thrift interface:

```java
public CompletableFuture<List<Long>> getFavourites(Long userId){
    CompletableFuture<List<Long>> future = new CompletableFuture();
    OctoThriftCallback callback = new OctoThriftCallback(thriftExecutor);
    callback.addObserver(new OctoObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            future.complete((List<Long>) o);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            future.completeExceptionally(throwable);
        }
    });
    try {
        recommendAsyncService.getFavorites(userId, callback);
    } catch (TException e) {
        log.error("OctoCall RecommendAsyncService.getFavorites", e);
    }
    return future;
}
```

Now it returns a CompletableFuture<List>. And then I call it to do some processor by using Flux.

```java
public Flux<Product> getRecommend(Long userId) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    // do not like it
    List<Long> recommendList = wrapper.getRecommend(userId).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println(recommendList);
    return Flux.fromIterable(recommendList)
            .flatMap(id -> Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(Product.builder()
                    .userId(userId)
                    .productId(id)
                    .productType((int) (Math.random()*100))
                    .build())))
            .take(5)
            .publishOn(mdpScheduler);
}
```

However, I want to get a Flux from `getFavourites` method and I can use it in `getRecommend` method.
Or, you can recommend a `Flux API` ,and I can convert the `List<Long> recommendList` to `Flux<Long> recommendFlux`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>` into a `Flux<T>` you can use [`Mono#fromFuture`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromFuture-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture-) with [`Mono#flatMapMany`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-):

```
var future = new CompletableFuture<List<Long>>();
future.completeAsync(() -> List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
    CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

Flux<Long> flux = Mono.fromFuture(future).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);

flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

`List<T>` received asynchronously in a callback can be also converted into a `Flux<T>` without using a `CompletableFuture`.
You can directly use [`Mono#create`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) with [`Mono#flatMapMany`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Flux<Long> flux = Mono.<List<Long>>create(sink -> {
  Callback<List<Long>> callback = new Callback<List<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(List<Long> list) {
      sink.success(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
      sink.error(e);
    }
  };
  client.call("query", callback);
}).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);

flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Or simply using [`Flux#create`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) with multiple emissions in one pass:

```
Flux<Long> flux = Flux.create(sink -> {
  Callback<List<Long>> callback = new Callback<List<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(List<Long> list) {
      list.forEach(sink::next);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
      sink.error(e);
    }
  };
  client.call("query", callback);
});

flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Int the part of directly using Mono#create with Mono#flatMapMany. I cannot realize the callback . Whether do i use wrong tool? Or you just supply a pseudocode?

Comment: @dyy.alex, `Callback` is an interface of class you have to create yourself. Or use the one supplied by the client library (a lib behind the `client` variable).

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution is to use `Flux.fromIterable` as shown in below example

```
public Flux<Integer> fromListToFlux(){
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,5,7);
    return Flux.fromIterable(intList);
}
```

Springboot version is 3.1.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Note: This is not recommended because it will not be completely reactive when you work out of the reactive pipeline, here creating a List.